# Modifying Birthday in Contact Info

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I'm trying to modify contact data, but I'm looking for a specific case. Is it possible to modify the birthday entry in a contact's data? If so, how can I go about this? I haven't been able to find anything on it...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the birthday of a contact as follows:

```
CFDateRef birthdayRef = (__bridge CFDateRef)birthday; // birthday is a NSDate
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty, birthdayRef, error);
```

where `person` is an instance of `ABRecordRef`.

For example, to set the birthday of a contact whose email address matches a variable called `targetEmailAddress`:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
{
    if (granted) {
        CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

            // Find the person with an email address matching  targetEmailAddress 
            ABMultiValueRef emailAddresses = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
            for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(emailAddresses); i++) {
                NSString *emailAddress = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailAddresses, i);

                if ([emailAddress isEqualToString:targetEmailAddress]) {        
                    // Set the person's birthday        
                    CFDateRef birthdayRef = (__bridge CFDateRef)birthday; // birthday is a NSDate
                    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty, birthdayRef, error);
                    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, error);

                    // Check for error here
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Follow this,

1. get the object of ABRecordRef (say person)from addressbook
2. remove aRecord from the address book
3. set the (changed ) values to aRecord
4. add record
5. save addressbook

//Create an instance of address book

```
ABAddressBookRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCreate();
```

//Get an instance of a personn with its index
// find you case with particular person

```
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(allPeople, rid);
```

//Copy the personn

```
ABRecordRef personCopy = person;
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM"];// your b'date format
        //don't set year in address book (yyyy=1604)

 NSDate *bdate=[formatter dateFromString:[formatter stringFromDate:@"10.12"]]; // 10.12 is your b'date.

 ABRecordSetValue(personCopy, kABPersonBirthdayProperty,(__bridge CFDateRef)bdate,nil);


CFErrorRef error;
BOOL remove = ABAddressBookRemoveRecord (
                           allPeople,
                           person,
                           &error);
if(remove) {
    BOOL add = ABAddressBookAddRecord (
                                 allPeople,
                                 personCopy,
                                 &error);
    BOOL save = ABAddressBookSave(allPeople, &error);
}
```